# splitting a string and storing it into an array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, struct, split

Part of the text file used:

```
Maths       H   B2 
Irish       O   C3 
English     O   B1
```

I am trying to split the strings into three arrays storing for example; maths into a subject array, H(higher level) into a level array and B2 into a grade array. Im doing this so it is then accessible later and easier to sort separately etc. The following is a code of me trying to split the strings in the array into three but want to store each one in a different array. This is my first assignment using structs so am new to this syntax and do not know how to do it.

```
SubjectResult split;

for(i=0; i<lineNum; i++){
    sscanf(ResultsArr[i],"%s %s %s",split.subject, split.level, split.grade);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make an array of structs.

```
SubjectResult split[MAXLINES];

for (i = 0; i < lineNum; i++) {
    sscanf(ResultsArr[i],"%s %s %s", split[i].subject, split[i].level, split[i].grade);
}
```

Comment: Thanks! would the strings be automatically broken up into three and stored in them array of structs then?

Comment: Your `sscanf` already splits them into 3. All I added was the way to keep them all in an array.

Comment: Thanks for the help!